# Stored credentials under my user profile when setting up Windows XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm working on getting Windows XP Mode installed on my 32-bit Windows 7 Ultimate machine.  I've made sure that the BIOS is OK, downloaded and installed both Virtual PC and Windows XP Mode.  Next I started setting it up.  I got a message  talking to me about where to set up the credentials, an administative account, etc.  My problem is that my C: drive isn't big enough for how large I want to make my virtual PC.  However, my PC does have 2 HD's, and my secondary HD (my D: drive) has plenty of free disk space, so I want to put as much as possible onto my D: drive.  My question is how do I make certain that as much as possible gets onto the D: drive?  Will putting the credentials under my profile, put the virtual drive there?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fight the OS to create space is the old way of doing things.

All the cool kids use Junctions and Symlinks. 
XP Mode uses two main files that space conscious users will want to be aware of.

%Appdata%\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines\Windows XP Mode.vhd 
%Program Files%\Windows XP Mode\Windows XP Mode base.vhd

You **could** try to tell the installer to install on another drive.

Or just install it, move the file and **drop a symlink**.

Comment: I've never heard of either Junctions or Symlinks.  Will have to do some research into this. Thanks!